# Covert MM:SS column to HH:MM:SS column in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, datetime, types, timedelta

Convert MM:SS column to HH:MM:SS column in Pandas. I tried every possible way, like changing datatype and to_datetime and to_timedelta, but I couldn't covert the series. Please help somebody. I am getting errors like:

(here chiptime is in MM:SS format, which I want to change in HH:MM:SS)

```py
df2["ChipTime"]=pd.to_datetime(df2.ChipTime, unit="hour").dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

> ValueError: cannot cast unit hour

```py
df2["ChipTime"]=pd.to_timedelta(df2["ChipTime"])
```

> ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format

```py
df2["ChipTime"]=df2["ChipTime"].astype(int)
```

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '16:48'

I have tried more methods, above are some of them, I am beginner in Pandas, so please excuse me if I have done any blunder. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If convert values to datetimes there are added default year, month, day with parameter format in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), if neccesary is possible convert values to times by [`Series.dt.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.time.html)

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ChipTime':['16:48','10:48']})

df2["ChipTime1"]=pd.to_datetime(df2.ChipTime, format="%M:%S")
df2["ChipTime11"]=pd.to_datetime(df2.ChipTime, format="%M:%S").dt.time
```

Or for timedeltas add `00:` for default hour by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df2["ChipTime2"]=pd.to_timedelta('00:' + df2["ChipTime"]) 
print (df2)
  ChipTime           ChipTime1 ChipTime11 ChipTime2
0    16:48 1900-01-01 00:16:48   00:16:48  00:16:48
1    10:48 1900-01-01 00:10:48   00:10:48  00:10:48
```